# Reading a dataset from Kaggle

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, kaggle

I am trying to download a dataset from kaggle, the link is:
https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/birdy654/cifake-real-and-ai-generated-synthetic-images
there is a download button in this link. The link of that is:
https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/birdy654/cifake-real-and-ai-generated-synthetic-images/download?datasetVersionNumber=3
I have a Jupyter project on my local machine. When I try to download the dataset using:

```
url = 'https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/birdy654/cifake-real-and-ai-generated-synthetic-images/download?datasetVersionNumber=3'
response = requests.get(url)

with open('cifake-real-and-ai-generated-synthetic-images.zip', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(response.content)
```

I get an html file, instead of the zip folder. I read online, and it seemed like I need a gaggle API token. I got that, then I put in in the folder, but the same issue persists. So right now the hierarchy of my folders is:

```
project -> [(.kaggle -> [kaggle.json]) and (file.ipynb)].
```

project has .kaggle folder and file.ipynb and inside .kaggle I have kaggle.json
I am also logged in to kaggle, so I am not sure why it keeps downloading the html file instead of the actual zip file.

Comment: Are you logged into Kaggle in the Python script? Being logged in on your browser does not automatically let you pass the login process when making the request in Python. You may not be able to do this directly with `requests`. Kaggle has [other ways to handle downloads for Python](https://www.kaggle.com/general/194531). Alternatively, download manually on your browser and read the file directly or upload it to another location for download such as your google drive

Comment: Yes I believe that is the only option at this point. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the Kaggle [Python API](https://www.kaggle.com/donkeys/kaggle-python-api):

```
import kaggle

kaggle.api.authenticate()

kaggle.api.dataset_download_files('birdy654/cifake-real-and-ai-generated-synthetic-images', path='CIFAKE', unzip=True)
```

Authentication with kaggle.json is detailed in the link above.

I have also uploaded the dataset to **GitHub** as an alternative which may be more useful, the repo can be found [**here**](https://github.com/jordan-bird/CIFAKE-Real-and-AI-Generated-Synthetic-Images).

If you have any further questions then feel free to get in touch. I hope our dataset is useful for your project, good luck!